# How to find finite trigonometric products

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, products

I wonder how to prove ?
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+2\cos\frac{2\pi 3^k}{3^n+1} \right)=1$$
give me a tip

Comment: Source?${}{}{}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson - do you suspect this question shouldn't be answered?

Comment: @nbubis, I just like to know where questions come from before I put a lot of time into them. If, for example, the statement is false, I don't want to waste a lot of time trying to prove it --- so I'd like some reason for believing it's true, some source, some reference.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
First prove that:
$$\prod_{k=0}^n\left(1+2\cos(3^k x)\right) = 1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^{m}\cos(kx)$$
Where:
$$m=\sum_{k=0}^n{3^k} = \frac{3^{1+n}-1}{2}$$

Then show that you are essentially sampling the $\cos$ function between $0$ and $2\pi$ at equal intervals, and since the average is equal to zero, the sum is therefore $1$, as required. To prove the first identity, you can use the Chebyshev relation:
$$\cos(nx)=2\cos(x)\cos((n-1)x)-\cos((n-2)x)$$

Comment: thanks!!      First prove ??(very difficult)
$$\prod_{k=0}^n\left(1+2\cos(3^k x)\right) = 1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^{m}\cos(kx)$$

Comment: @user59343 - you asked for a tip.. as I said, you can get this using the Chebyshev relation and starting from the left hand side.

Comment: @user59343 - is that a question? please try to use english as well.

Comment: is it true? $$\sum_{k=1}^{ \frac{3^{1+n}-1}{2}} \cos kx=0$$ where $x=\frac{2\pi}{3^n+1}$

Comment: Dear nbubis. I'm sorry. The essence of the previous question is that how I can finish the proof from the first Identity

Comment: @user59343 - can you state where the question is from? I'll try and give a full proof / or a bounty for it.

Comment: It is first introduced as a question of university admission tests for special(smart) students, South Korea, a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n 3^k = \frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$.  Then

$$3^{n}- S_{n-1} = 3^{n} - \frac{3^{n}-1}{2} = \frac{3^{n}+1}{2} = S_{n-1}+1.
$$

Now by induction we have the following product identity for $n \geq 0$:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{k=0}^{n}\left(z^{3^k}+1+z^{-3^k}\right) &=& \left(z^{3^{n}}+1+z^{-3^{n}}\right)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(z^{3^k}+1+z^{-3^k}\right) \\
&=& \left(z^{3^{n}}+1+z^{-3^{n}}\right) \left(\sum_{k=-S_{n-1}}^{S_{n-1}} z^k\right) \\
&=&\sum_{k=S_{n-1}+1}^{S_n}z^k + \sum_{k=-S_{n-1}}^{S_{n-1}}z^k+\sum_{k=-S_n}^{-S_{n-1}-1} z^k \\
&=& \sum_{k=-S_n}^{S_n} z^k
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Now take $z = \exp\left(\frac{\pi \, i}{3^n + 1}\right)$ and use that $z^{3^n+1}=-1$ to get

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{k=0}^n\left(1 + 2 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi \,3^k}{3^n+1}\right)\right) &=& \sum_{k=-S_n}^{S_n}z^{2k} = \frac{z^{2S_n+1}-z^{-2S_n-1}}{z-z^{-1}} = \frac{z^{3^{n+1}}-z^{-3^{n+1}}}{z-z^{-1}} \\
&=& \frac{z^{3(3^n+1)-3} - z^{-3(3^n+1)+3}}{z-z^{-1}} = \frac{z^3-z^{-3}}{z-z^{-1}} = z^2 + 1 + z^{-2} \\
&=& 1 + 2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3^n+1}\right)
\end{eqnarray}$$

and your identity follows.

Comment: But the identity in the OP says that the big product is equal to $1$, while your identity says it is equal to $1 + 2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3^n+1}\right)$ ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy look at the range of the index $k$.

Comment: indeed. One slightly different index changes everything ...